Show that $(3,\sqrt [3]{11}+1)$ is a principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{11}]$
I know how to verify $(3,\sqrt [3]{11}+1)=(\sqrt[3]{11}-2)$:
$(\sqrt[3]{11}-2)(\sqrt[3]{121}+2\sqrt[3]{11}+4)=11-8=3$ and then $\sqrt[3]{11}+1=\sqrt[3]{11}-2+3$
But if I don't know the answer, how can I compute it explicitly? Thank you for your answer.

If I understand correctly, your queestion is: how do we argue if we are not told what principal ideal we are looking for ? In that case my instinct would  be to compute the norm of the ideal, and see which elements share this norm.

@FançoisGatine Yes, assume $(3,\sqrt[3]{11})=(\beta)$ and then $N\big((3,\sqrt[3]{11})\big)=3=N\big((\beta)\big)$. Let $\beta=a\sqrt[3]{121}+b\sqrt[3]{11}+c$, the equality will give some information on $a,b,c$. But I think it is not enough to deduce what are the values of $a,b,c$.

The norm of $\beta$ is $c^3 + 11b^3 + 11^2 a^3 - 11abc$. Looking at congruences, you can show that $c = 9$ mod $11$ and $a+2b+c = 0$ mod $3$.
Unless anyone has a better idea, I would try assuming $a=0$, so the norm simply becomes $c^3 + 11b^3$, and use trial and error with the $(b,c)$ satisfying the congruence conditions...

@FançoisGatine Thank you for the comment. Can I show that this is a principal ideal without computing? As it's a little complicated. I wonder if I can get around it.

One abstract way would be, if you are familiar with that, to compute the class group of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{11})$, and either show that it is trivial (which, I don't know if that is the case), which would imply that every ideal of the integer ring is principal. Or more generally, if you can compute the class group and show how your ideal decomposes into a product of primes, you could use the class group structure to argue that it is principal. But computing the class group is HARD in general.

@FançoisGatine Thank you very much for the idea! To tell the truth, I came up with this question when I tried to compute the ideal class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{11})$, haha. Anyway, very appreciated to your detailed information.

@FançoisGatine You may want to check on that norm. Usually is cube root fields there's a factor of $3$ in the trilinear term so in this case I would get $c^3+11b^3+121a^3-33abc$. If I put $a=b=c=1$, expecting a norm of $100$ given this is $10/(\sqrt[3]{11}-1)$, I get that value with $33$ not $11$ in the trilinear term.

@OscarLanzi Yep, that was a typo, thanks

I am confused by the closing. The duplicated question serms to have the square root if $11$ not the cube root.

My solution is tricky and not general.
The ring is $A = \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^3 - 11)$. In $A/(X + 1)$, $0 = X^3 - 11 = (-1)^3 -11 = -12$. So $A/(X+1) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(12)$. Now it is easy to see that $A/(X+1, 3) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(3)$. We may think about an ideal $(a)$ such that $A/(a) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(3)$.
Now you see that $X-2$ is in the $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of $3, X+1$. And $A/(X-2) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(3)$. So $(X-2) = (3, X+1)$.

Please don’t write $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to denote the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. The notation $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is reserved for $p$-adic numbers, especially in the context of algebraic number theory.

To be fair, the notation $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ might be confused with $\mathbb Z^2/n$, as $a/bc$ can be interpreted as $(a/b)c$ or $a/(bc)$. Though it's usually the latter, for example if you type $1/2x$ on wolframAlpha you will find it equal to $x/2$.

@Aphelli It seems you are not aware that the notation $,\Bbb Z_n := \Bbb Z/n,$ is widely used in elementary number theory. There is little chance of confusion.

Therefore $\mathbb Z_n$ is a better more unambiguous way to write it, or $\mathbb Z/(n\mathbb Z)$ is fine too
